# About TCP protocol implementation

Tags: ros, tcpros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm making a client from Pharo smalltalk (Pharo 1.4 with the latest CogVM) (To be used from a different machine of the ROS installed). My first goal is make work the turtle simulator from my client.

Considering:

- a remote client (without direct access to server)
- an ubuntu ROS instalation
- How can i get the message definition related to a topic? Can i ask to the topic? Does the topic answer me in the error text something about the type? (AFAIK, browsing the topic-tools implementation, this kind of data is based on file browsing)
- Is any definition of a common TCPROS package to take as example of topic usage?

  In this case, i'd spend a lot of time today trying to send messages to the turtle throgh the velocity topic without any response (no movement, no error, no feedback at all) and i tried with the logs, but without any useful data.

The process i'm following is:

start roscore
start turtle node

then, from the client

register as publisher in Velocity topic via XMLRPC layer
with the IP:PORT recived connect to the node with a TCP/ip connection
then i send a message with:

header
type: master getTopicTypeRelated:/turtle1/command_velocity;  #here i get the topicType from getTopicTypes
topic: /turtle1/command_velocity;
latching: false;
callerId: anArbitraryId;
messageDefinition: 'float32 linear
float32 angular';
md5Sum:'9d5c2dcd348ac8f76ce2a4307bd63a13'.

in the body of the request i tried with float numbers (2.0 0.0) for example.

All this data in binary.

I browse a lot of roscpp, rospy and rosjava code trying to find how them create and serialize the data, but i dont find meaningful differences. I browse the site and the questions several times and i didnt find extensive explanations of the protocol. Maybe am i missing steps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43810/about-tcp-protocol-implementation/) by [sbragagnolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3205/sbragagnolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you haven't yet, take a look at the ROS master and slave APIs: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Master_Slave_APIs . If you're writing a client implementation, it should provide the slave API.

There's some documentation on the TCPROS protocol here, that should help with your development: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/TCPROS

There's a lot of debugging built into the C++ client library, but it's turned off by default. If you use rxconsole or rxloggerlevel, you can turn on debug statements that should give some insight into why the C++ subscribers are having a hard time with your messages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5